# Class doesn't exist in current schema after being added to migration

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, realm-migration

I've been struggling performing a simple migration. What I just want to achieve is add a new Class in realm.

The code below is inside a method that is called inside onCreate.

```kotlin
        Realm.init(this)

        val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("db_name")
                .schemaVersion(5L)
                .migration { realm, oldVersion, newVersion ->
                    val schema = realm.schema
                    var _oldVersion = oldVersion
                    if (_oldVersion == 4L) {
                        if (schema.contains(XModel::class.java.simpleName))
                            schema.remove(XModel::class.java.simpleName)

                        if (!schema.contains(XModel::class.java.simpleName))
                            schema.create(XModel::class.java.simpleName)
                                    .addField(XModel::id.name, Long::class.javaPrimitiveType,
                                            FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                                    ...
                                    .addField(XModel::N.name, Int::class.javaPrimitiveType)
                        _oldVersion += 1
                    }
                }
                .build()

        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
```

As what the title suggest, the new class in the schema was created inside the migration object, but when I try to access it in other parts of the application using a realm query or a simple call to `schema.get("XModel")` it will throw an error `XModel doesn't exist in current schema.` Any comment will really help. Thank you...

**Edit:**

Additional information. I have 2 realm objects, each are in different android modules, one module is dependent to the other. I somehow have some progress, now Im a bit confuse, do I need to declare 2 configurations? Then it would mean 2 realm instance? How to switch from both, I want to merge them into 1 realm.

**Edit2:**

Another clarification about realm. If you have 2 android modules, each of them using realm, will they have different realm even if in the realm configuration they have the same name?

**Background**

I want to give you a background of what im doing because I think its needed to fully understand my case.

Originally I only have one module, but then after refactoring and also because of future apps to be develop, I need to pull out the common classes from the existing module and put it in a separate lower-level module that the future apps can depend on. This new lower-level module will also be responsible for most of the data layer, so realm was transferred to this module. But I can't just ignore the realm of the existing app because some users might already populated it, and I need to transfer those data to the new database.

Comment: I was struggling with a very similar issue, the new class in the schema was created inside the migration object but I couldn't access it. I was able to overcome the problem by adding .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded() before the .build() in the builder. But be aware that this will delete all the data on your realm database. That's why I am sure this is not the best solution, but it my help if you have not got much time to solve it

Comment: Yeah thanks @MateoHervas, it may be a solution if I haven't launched the app yet, but I already have a live one in the store with user data, so. I appreciate your response mate.